# How to compare derived class object with Base class object java?

Tags: java

How do I compare Base class object with derived class object in derived class? I need to get `true` as output from the code below:

```
class Base {
    int i;
    String str;
}

class Derived extends Base{
    double d;
    String str1;

    public static void main(String []a){
        Base b= new Base();
        Derived d = new Derived();
        System.out.println("Equals! :"+d.equals(b));
    }
}
```

It always gives me `false` as output. How can I compare base class with derived class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Object equality is usually defined for objects of the same class, e.g.: You might want two objects `Base b1, b2` to be equal if their `str` and `i` values are equal. Then you would need to define the `equals()` (and, typically, `hashCode()`) methods to test for this condition. For example:

```
public boolean equals(Object obj)
{
    // test for identity
    if (this == obj) return true;

    // check that obj is not null, and that it is an instance of Base
    if (obj == null) return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) return false;

    // compare attributes
    Base other = (Base) obj;
    if (i != other.i) return false;
    if (str == null && other.str != null) return false;
    if (!str.equals(other.str)) return false;
    return true;
}
```

In your case, since `Base` and `Derived` are different classes, with different attributes (`Base` has `str` and `i`, while `Derived` has `str`, `i`, `str1`, and `d`), you would need to define exactly when are a `Base` object and a `Derived` object supposed to be equal.

Answer (score 1):

Well, to make it just return true is easy enough:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object other) {
    return true;
}
```

However, I'd argue that that's not what you *should* be doing (even in a somewhat less trivial implementation).

I think the `equals` method from `Object` shouldn't return `true` unless the types are actually the same. Otherwise it ends up making life really tricky in terms of making sure that the symmetry aspects required by `Object.equals(Object)` are fulfilled. It also doesn't feel like it's fulfilling *natural* equality at that point.

However, it would be entirely reasonable to write an class which is able to compare any two instances of `Base` for equality in your specific case. The nice thing about equality comparators is that they don't have to be as natural - you're not defining what equality should mean for the whole type - you're just describing one specific comparison.

It's unfortunate that Java doesn't have an `EqualityComparator<T>` (or whatever) interface to go with `Comparator<T>`. It makes it much harder to create (say) maps and sets which use a specific idea of equality (and a hash code to go with it). That may or may not be a problem in your case - how are you hoping to use this equality comparison anyway? If it's in your own code, you could write your own `EqualityComparator<T>` interface. If you're going to build a map or set, it's not going to be as easy :(